# DigitalOcean Ansible view registered variable

Tags: ansible, digital-ocean

I'm experimenting with throwing DigitalOcean droplets up using Ansible. This should allow me to have it all nice and infrastructure-as-code. I've experimented with the dynamic inventory plugin, but it's not quite what I'm after at the moment.

```
- name: Add droplet
  digital_ocean: >
    state=present
    command=droplet
    name={{ item.key }}
    size_id=512mb
    region_id=ams2
    image_id={{ item.value.image_id }}
    ssh_key_ids={{ my_ssh_key.ssh_key.id }}
    unique_name=yes
  with_dict: "{{ droplets_up }}"
  register: my_droplet

- debug: msg="Droplet ID is {{ my_droplet.droplet.id }}"
```

Don't worry about all the variables - the droplet comes up as expected, however, the debug step fails with:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'droplet'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/Users/jerry/free_code/d-ocean/ansible/roles/dropletctl/tasks/main.yml': line 23, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- debug: msg=\"Droplet ID is {{ my_droplet.droplet.id }}\"\n  ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"}

However, if I run the play in verbose mode, I can see that the variable should exist. An example very like this is used on the Ansible modules documentation page, so I assume it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this off, the way to "drill down" into the verbose output of the debug output is as follows:

```
- name: Print droplets variable
  debug:
    msg: "{{ my_droplet.results | map(attribute='droplet.<variable you'd like to print>') | list }}"
```

..where  is e.g. `ip_address`